# Meteor: How do I convert HTML/HTML5 code to work with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I've downloaded a HTML5/JS app but I do not think they code works with Meteor. Given the example below, where or how do I go about converting it so it works with Meteor? (since the rest of my web app is built on Meteor)

```
<template name="scratch">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>scratch.js - Example 1</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scratch.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function callback(d) { d.container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(assets/images/demo1-end.gif)'; d.container.innerHTML = ''; }
            function percent(p) { document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = p; }
            window.onload = function() {
                createScratchCard({
                    "container":document.getElementById("scratchcard"),
                    "background":"assets/images/demo1-background.png",
                    "foreground":"assets/images/demo1-foreground.png",
                    "percent":85,
                    "coin":"assets/images/coin2.png",
                    "thickness":18,
                    "counter":"percent",
                    "callback":"callback"
                });
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            body { text-align: center; }
            #scratchcard { display: block; width: 180px; height: 180px; margin: 40px auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scratchcard"></div>
        <span id="counter">0</span><span>%</span>
    </body>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion it to use https://github.com/websanova/wScratchPad .

Just download and add minified version in client/compatibility

Then you can just do:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
    $('#scratchcard').wScratchPad({
          size        : 5,          // The size of the brush/scratch.
          bg          : '#cacaca',  // Background (image path or hex color).
          fg          : '#6699ff',  // Foreground (image path or hex color).
          realtime    : true,       // Calculates percentage in realitime.
          cursor      : 'crosshair' // Set cursor.
        });
});
```

Also there are three additional callbacks in which returns percent, so you will be able to update...

```
scratchDown : null,       // Set scratchDown callback.
scratchUp   : null,       // Set scratchUp callback.
scratchMove : null,       // Set scratcMove callback.
```

Note: it depends on JQuery

Comment: thank you for that... i'd like to set that when a certain % been scratched, the site will reveal a link and also reveal the entire image... where do i look?

Comment: `$('#scratchcard').wScratchPad({
          size        : 5,          // The size of the brush/scratch.
          bg          : '#cacaca',  // Background (image path or hex color).
          fg          : '#6699ff',  // Foreground (image path or hex color).
          realtime    : true,       // Calculates percentage in realitime.
          cursor      : 'crosshair' // Set cursor.
          scratchDown:function(percent){
              if(percent > 50){
                    do somthing
              }
          }
        }); `

Comment: scratchDown : function(percent){ 
           if(percent > 50){ console.log('eh'); } 
          } 
      });  did that but console log showed nothing... also, i followed their github but nothing returned too... did function(e,percent)... must i import their whole package?

Comment: scratchDown: function(e, percent){ console.log(percent); },

Triggers when start scratching card

scratchMove: function(e, percent){ console.log(percent); },

Triggers while scratching card

scratchUp: function(e, percent){ console.log(percent); }

Triggers when end scratching card

Comment: e.g.:
scratchMove: function(e, percent){
              $('#counter').html(percent.toFixed(0));
          },

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your `scratch.min.js` file in `client/compatibility` [special folder](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).
2. Move your `style` CSS content into a CSS file.
3. Move the content of your `body` into an HTML file, inside a `body` as well (and if you wish through a template).
4. Move the content of your `script` in a JavaScript file (and if you wish through the same template hooks).
5. If you have moved your HTML content directly in `body`, replace `window.onload` by [`Meteor.startup()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-startup) hook. If you the HTML content is part of a template, use instead the [`Template.myTemplate.onRendered()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered) hook (assuming you are using Blaze).

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is to separate view, styles, and controller in 3 files.

scratch.html

```
<template name="scratch">
    <body>
        <div id="scratchcard"></div>
        <span id="counter">0</span><span>%</span>
    </body>
</template>
```

scratch.css

```
body { text-align: center; }
#scratchcard { display: block; width: 180px; height: 180px; margin: 40px auto; }
```

scratch.js

```
    function callback(d) { 
       d.container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(assets/images/demo1-end.gif)';
       d.container.innerHTML = ''; 
    }
    function percent(p) { 
       document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = p; 
    }

    Template.scratch.onRendered(function(){
       createScratchCard({
                    "container":document.getElementById("scratchcard"),
                    "background":"assets/images/demo1-background.png",
                    "foreground":"assets/images/demo1-foreground.png",
                    "percent":85,
                    "coin":"assets/images/coin2.png",
                    "thickness":18,
                    "counter":"percent",
                    "callback":"callback"
                });
    });
```

and Add your scratch.min.js file in client/compatibility

Comment: I tried this and tried to run it, it just shows 0%. However if I run these files how it was originally with google chrome dev, it works fine. note that when i run this locally normally just opening from the folder, it does the same...